# Evaluating the safety of deep RL algorithms

Tags: reinforcement-learning

Is there any free/open-source environment, tasks, or dataset for evaluating deep RL algorithms in terms of safety?
all available environments (like openAI's) are environments for simple games. These can be  useful in evaluating the algorithms in terms of sample efficiency, variance and speed of training. However, How can someone evaluate the deep RL algorithms in terms of safety?

Comment: Is this relevant? https://verifieddeeplearning.com/